How does ssis read the underlying data type?
I have an excel file with 1 column values of type number with 2 digits after the decimal. Example: 21.00
In my ssis package I added a excel data source that plugs to this file.
I can see that the input column format is double precision float. The output format is also double precious float.
If I store this into the db table [column type varchar(100)], then it gets stored as 20.999999999
Whereas if I change the excel data source task's output column property to DT_DECIMAL, then the data goes into the db table as 21.00
What's going on behind the scenes?
I understand ssis reads the first 8 values to determine the data type. But what causes the above behaviour.

You are right ! SSIS reads the first 8 rows to determine the data type. This is controlled by the "TypeGuessRows" setting in the registry which can be configured to a different value (I don't recommend changing it).
For numerical values, SSIS might interpret the data as a double precision float (DT_R8) if it sees decimal points in the initial rows.
DT_R8 is a floating-point data type that can have precision issues because it represents numbers in a way that allows for a large range but can also lead to small rounding errors, which is why you see 21.00 being stored as 20.999999999 in your db when you map it to a varchar field.
On the other side DT_DECIMAL is a fixed-point numeric data type with exact precision and scale that's why the value 21.00 is preserved when you explicitly convert to DT_DECIMAL.
If I follow the logic behind , what happened is when SSIS reads the data as DT_R8 it stores the floating-point number as is which can result in minor precision error.
When you store this value in as a varchar, SQL Server (I guess) converts the float to a string representation which may expose these small precision errors (like 20.999999999 instead of 21.00).
When you choose DT_DECIMAL, SSIS forces the data to maintain its exact decimal precision before it's stored in the db, so it is preserving the 21.00.
Some links to help you :
https://sqlsrv4living.blogspot.com/2018/08/ssis-import-mixed-data-types-from-ms.html
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/bi-sql-server/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/
https://www.databasejournal.com/ms-sql/importing-excel-data-into-ssis-2008-using-data-conversion-transformation/

So should I modify the external column data type of the excel data source task, OR should I add a data conversion task? What is correct way to read the data.

You may do both :) (I would go for a conversion task for tracking)

If I set it to dt_decimal in the external column of the excel data source advanced editor, then isn't this applied after the data is read from excel. So my point is that- if the data read is approximate, then how would converting it to decimal or numeric be of any help? Are you getting my point.
